# Как убрать из математического выражения лишние скобки?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, очередь

Попалась такая задача: «при помощи очереди изъять лишние скобки из арифметического выражения». Изначально она показалась очень простой, но на практике вызвала много затруднений.

Добавление **@mymedia**:

Лишними скобками считаются те, которые можно убрать, сохранив смысл выражения. Например, `(5*7)+3` → `5*7+3`, `((a+b))` → `a+b`.

Comment: Почему при помощи очереди, а не через стек?

Comment: @soon даже стек тут не поможет. Надо убрать ЛИШНИЕ. Попадалась такая задача в свое время - делал через разложение выражения по польской нотации в дерево, а потом сборка обратно с подстановкой скобок только там, где надо

Comment: @АлексейСаровский А в чем проблема? Находим открывающую - заносим ее индекс. Находим закрывающую - убираем индекс. Не можем убрать индекс - выкидываем закрывающую. Если после обработки строки остались открывающие - выкидываем и их.

Comment: @soon ((a+b)) Как здесь сработает Ваш алгоритм?

Comment: @АлексейСаровский, не так понял задание, считал, что лишние - нарушающие правильность выражения.

Comment: @soon думаю что лишние - это ну вот прям лишние) Которые не нужны

Comment: 5+(6*4) - вот тут скобки тоже явно лишние. Но эту задачу без синтаксического анализа точно не решить...

Comment: @Harry прикрепил ответ - так точно можно

Comment: @АлексейСаровский Ну так ваш вариант - это одна из разновидностей синтаксического анализа :)

Comment: @mymedia Вы зря добавили в вопрос, что именно считается *лишними* скобками. Откровенно говоря, у меня ощущение - **из постановки задачи преподом** - что имются в виду скобки повторные, типа `((a+b))+c -> (a+b)+c`. В любом случае *до разъяснений автора вопроса* я бы поостерегся делать такие уточнения.

Comment: @Harry, ладно mymedia, но почему эта правка вообще получила подтверждение?

Comment: @Harry, надеюсь, автор увидит правку и, если это ему не подходит, исправит

Comment: @soon  VenZell и Владимир Мартьянов приняли эту правку.

Comment: @mymedia `((a+b))+c -> a+b+c` нет разве?

Answer (score 4):

Задача действительно не самая простая и через стек ее не решить. Через стек решается задача определения правильности/неправильности скобочной последовательности. Лишние скобки так не убрать. [ВОТ](http://algolist.manual.ru/syntax/revpn.php) можно почитать про обратную польскую нотацию. Раскладываете выражение, собираете обратно и где надо ставите скобки. Тогда лишних уже не будет.

P.S. очередь/стек там используется для сохранения операций.

Comment: Откопал код (на 2 курсе делали). Автор темы, если надо - отпишись, как-нибудь передам тебе.

Comment: была бы очень благодарна, kristina.ergardt@yandex.ru